Can I truncate 10-byte "extended" number and convert as an 8-byte double?
I'm playing with AIFF files, which include an 80-bit "extended" format value which defines the sample rate.  Since neither my language of choice, R, nor my desktop Mac, natively supports this size, I need to write conversion code.  Given the data structure of the bits, as shown here, and in this image from that page
  ,
Can I simply truncate the 'fraction' part on the assumption that I'll never see a sample rate of that high a precision?  That is, can I grab the 64 bits starting on the left and treat them as a double float?    Note that the number of valid bits in the exponent must be truncated as well, per the chart in this question
A minimal example:  I verified the sample rate in a test file is 44100 .
The 10 bytes read from the AIFF header are:
40 0e ac 44 00 00 00 00 00 00

edit
ac 44 as 4 raw bytes converted to decimal becomes 44100, which is the sample rate I'd expect.

Yes, if you truncate the fraction and adjust the exponent it should work, but the bit-twiddling required can be tricky.  (That is, it's not just "grab the 64 bits starting on the left".) For extra credit you can make sure the new fraction is correctly rounded, not just truncated.

I think you need to take the 15-bit exponent and subtract 15360 from it, then re-store it as 11 bits (assuming it fits).

Oh, one more thing. The Intel 80-bit extended format stores the significand's leading 1 bit explicitly (the "integer part" in the figure), so further adjustments are required.

@SteveSummit  thanks-- you're confirming a bunch of my suspicions.  I'll set up some bit-shift ops and see what luck I have.

Here is a direct approach which doesn't require any truncation.

convert the 15-bit exponent.  Follow the standard procedure for doubles, but now calculate ExpMul = 2^(exponent - 16383) ; the latter number being 2^14 -1 .

Store the lead bit of the mantissa (equivalent to the implicit "1" in doubles).  Calculate the value of the remaining bits as a decimal fraction.  (Note: I used bigBits:fracB2B for this).

multiply (lead_bit + fraction) * (ExpMul)  .


My sample value in fact produced 44100 , as I expected to find.
